# Batch file to copy local folder to FTP server fails with "cannot open file" on "put *"

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I found some posts on similar issues but I did not make my problem to work.
I want to use Windows Task on Windows Server 2012 to copy the content of some folders to back them up on a FTP server.

I created a `filebakup.bat` and entered these lines

```
@echo off
echo user myusername> ftpcmd.dat
echo mypassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd /D "G:\Navi_Touren\Tour_2015\">> ftpcmd.dat   *the local dir with many files to transfer
echo cd /backups/Tour_2015>> ftpcmd.dat  *the Destination Folder on ftp  
echo put *>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat myFTPserver.com
```

It does not work, it says "cannot open file" or similar error message.

I can only make it with one file

```
echo put "G:\Navi_Touren\Tour_2015\myfile.txt"  "/backups/Navi Touren/myfile.txt">> ftpcmd.dat
```

But how to transfer all files in a certain directory?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`mput *`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mput_1), instead of the `put`. The `put` does not accept wildcards.

Plus you want to use the [`prompt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-prompt_1) to disable confirmation of every selected file.

```
prompt
mput *
```

See also [Batch file to upload all files in directory to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39502163/850848).

---

Also there no `/D` switch in the `lcd` command. Remove that. And the trailing backslash does not seem to work either.

```
lcd "G:\Navi_Touren\Tour_2015"
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not manage it with mput *. mput just takes the files in the current Folder, but not those in the local source Folder. I could not find any working solution for more files on the net! Even mput *.rar failed. I would appreciate a whole script to adapt it to my Folder and files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my updated answer. If you have problems, make sure you inspect the output of the `ftp` or share it with us.

Comment: Besides the Problem above I have another Problem which I cannot solve at all, which is, that It seems as Windows does not accept a passive mode which is required most probably. I tried with a backup-Software (Cobian) which works fine as Long as passive mode is enabled. Same with FileZilla. In Windows I added passive (tried pasvr too) in the script, but it does not work. I found that passive mode is only for unix. Thanks yr. help, but I manage my issue with Cobian, iso Windows Task. Michael