# Batch file to upload directory to ftp server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

My programming background is generally limited to embedded C or assembly, and I'm having troubles writing a (what seems like it should be simple) batch file.

I am trying to write a script to upload an entire directory to an FTP server and REPLACE the existing directory that is up there.  I have edited batch files before, but I have never created one on my own, so sorry if I have a simple mistake.

To replace the folder on the server, I was going to delete the existing (which I haven't yet figured out how to do) and then upload the folder.  However, with the code below that I have put together from the internet, I have not been able to upload an entire directory.

```
@echo off
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put "C:\Dropbox\Capacity Energy\Partners\EMC2\FTP to Portal\2016-2017 Projects" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat FTPSERVER
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks incredibly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829485/batch-file-to-copy-local-folder-to-ftp-server-fails-with-cannot-open-file-on except it's not a duplicate, he's just trying to do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Yep, use `mput` rather than `put`.  You also need a wildcard.  `...\2016-2017 Projects\*"` I think.  I'm unable to test, but I think you might also need the `-i` switch in your `ftp` command.  Maybe adding `-i` would let you `del *`.  Last bit of advice, each time you do `> ftpcmd.dat` or `>> ftpcmd.dat`, you're closing then reopening the file for appending.  You should just `>ftpcmd.dat ( echo user USERNAME \n echo PASSWORD \n echo cd /path/to/dir \n etc... )` (replacing each `\n` with a new line), `echo`ing multiple lines into a single file creation session.

Comment: @rojo - you can use `mdel *` to delete everything.

Comment: Put the echos (without redirection) into a separate bat file makeftpscript.bat and call it, redirecting the output: call makeftpscript >ftpcmd.dat   Also you need a cd after bin, otherwise you're uploading to the user root which is probably not your intention.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I am really close, I have everything uploading, but I am having trouble replacing the existing directory.  I am using rmdir to try and delete it before uploading the new version.  When I call rmdir, it says "550 '/PART/AutoUpload' not deleted: Operation was successful.."  That is confusing to me, it wasn't successful if it didn't delete it.

Comment: As @SomethingDark already mentioned, use `mdel *` to delete the directory contents. If you have additional questions, ask them in separate posts. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.